# Insert itemized contents in a table

Tags: tables, lists

I am trying to produce the table in the attached picture to no avail. I couldn't reach a solution. I tried multicolumn, just to try, and then used `\table`, `\tabular`, and `tabularx` (I have a vague idea about the difference between the last two, it was a trial and error method).
The itemized contents need to have a minimum distance between bullets and texts, and the end of each line should be left aligned (as shown). Rows should also be closer to each other (`\itemsep0` did not work when I was trying.) I am also trying to make the bullet size `\LARGE`.[image]

Comment: Do you really need a table or just text in two columns?

Comment: It's just text in two columns. It has to be itemized, span all available width `\textwidth` and bullets should be of larger size. Distance between rows should be smaller, and so is the space between bullets and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using just `tabularx`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{{\Large$\bullet$}\quad}Xl@{\qquad{\Large$\bullet$}\quad}Xl}
 R, Matlab \dotfill  & 3--4 yrs & Administrative skills \dotfill  & 1 yr \\ 
 Excel, SQL \dotfill  & 1--2 yrs & Applied math research  \dotfill  & 3--1 yr \\    
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend the `dotfill` to the number of yrs? Also, how may I reduce the space between bullets and text?

Comment: Put `@{}` (i.e., nothing) before the `l` column and the dots with touch the numbers. However, it will look better with a small space : `@{\,}`. Equally, fell free to change `\quad` and `\qquad` by any other horizontal spacer. There are a lot of them ... including `\hspace{<what you want exacty>}`.

Comment: Excellent. I added `\hspace{0.5em}` instead of \quad to reduce space size between bullets and text. Thank you. Can you update your answer so it would be complete?

Comment: Is there a way to remove a bullet from one of the items? For example, one column could have one more row than the second, and the current code adds a bullet to the second column even though it has no item.

Comment: No, but instead of add bullets automatically before a column with `@{ }`  you can add a  new  `c` column add type  (or not) the bullets manually in each cell .  For the space bullet-text you can still  use `@{...}` and/or set `\tabcolsep`